# PostgreSQL LEFT OUTER JOIN Conditionals not working

Tags: sql, postgresql, join, conditional-statements

This LEFT OUTER JOIN with several conditionals is not working, it's probably something obvious. It is returning the result of all distinct sid and not performing conditionals at all.

```
SELECT
 count(distinct student_status.sid)
FROM studentcoursedb.student_status
      LEFT OUTER JOIN studentcoursedb.student_status AS t0
        ON t0.sid = student_status.sid
      AND t0.term < student_status.term
      AND student_status.major LIKE 'ABC%';
```

The result, 32684 is the count of total distinct sids, the same value returned by this query:

```
select count(distinct sid)
from studentcoursedb.student_status;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two query

```
SELECT
 count(distinct student_status.sid)
FROM studentcoursedb.student_status
      LEFT OUTER JOIN studentcoursedb.student_status AS t0
        ON t0.sid = student_status.sid
      AND t0.term < student_status.term
      AND student_status.major LIKE 'ABC%';


select count(distinct sid)
from studentcoursedb.student_status;
```

return the same number of rows  correctly because

You are  left  joining (left join or left outer join is the same) the same table   this mean that the resulting number of rows is ever the same number of the main table

If you want a subset matching you should use inner join  (or other join  relation)

Comment: The number of rows might be bigger if it is not 1:1 relation (but obviously, not the number of distinct values)

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz   correct  but im referring only at the number of .distinct rows ( and at this specific condition )

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure that the query is doing what I want it to but this answered my question. I am trying to check all students who transferred into a major with 'ABC' in it, from an older term to a newer one. Does this seem to be doing that?

Comment: @AlexElkman Try with inner join instead of left join .. in this way you should obtain only the  student that match and so you can count only this ..

Answer (score 0):

You are counting a column from the left table that might have duplicate rows as a result of the LEFT JOIN, but certainly no filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

A `LEFT OUTER JOIN` keeps all rows in the *first* table along with matching rows in the second.  Hence, it does not filter the first table.  You are counting a column from the first table.  So, the `LEFT OUTER JOIN` does not affect the distinct count.

If you want to filter rows, then use `INNER JOIN` instead.  I would also move the conditions to the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT count(distinct ss.sid)
FROM studentcoursedb.student_status ss INNER JOIN     
     studentcoursedb.student_status ss2
     ON ss2.sid = ss.sid
WHERE ss2.term < ss.term AND ss.major LIKE 'ABC%';
```

I should note that I don't think you need a self join.  Have you considered:

```
select dense_rank(ss.term) over (order by term)
from studentcoursedb.student_status ss
where ss.major like 'ABC%';
```

Much simpler and should have better performance.